# R Faster way to create lag by entire group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a simple data.table as follows-

```
  ID = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 1000), rep("C", 1000), rep("D", 1000))
  val = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c","d","d","d","d","e","e","f","f","g","g","g","g","g")

  dt = data.table(ID, val)
```

I want to add a new column to this data.table which will have the lag of `val` by group `ID`.

Here is the expected output

```
> head(dt, 20)
     ID val val_lag
 1:  A   a    <NA>
 2:  A   a    <NA>
 3:  A   a    <NA>
 4:  A   b       a
 5:  A   b       a
 6:  A   c       b
 7:  A   c       b
 8:  A   d       c
 9:  A   d       c
10:  A   d       c
11:  A   d       c
12:  A   e       d
13:  A   e       d
14:  A   f       e
15:  A   f       e
16:  A   g       f
17:  A   g       f
18:  A   g       f
19:  A   g       f
20:  A   g       f
```

The current solution I am using is -

```
dt[, val_lag := with(rle(val), rep(c(NA, head(values, -1)), lengths)), by = ID]
```

However, this solution is super slow on the actual dataset, which is very large and has millions of rows. Is there any faster way to solve this problem?

Following is the performance result of all methods discussed in this post -

```
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(rles = dt[, val_lag1 := with(rle(val), rep(c(NA, head(values, -1)), lengths)), by = ID],
                                 chinsoon = dt[, val_lag := shift(val)[nafill(replace(seq.int(.N), rowid(rleid(val)) > 1L, NA_integer_), "locf")], by = ID],
                                 TiC = dt[, val_lag3 := c(NA,rle(val)$values)[cumsum(c(0,head(val,-1)!=tail(val,-1)))+1], by = ID],
                                 times = 1000
  )

Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
     rles 1.549548 1.781014 2.750187 2.096805 2.743668 46.65326  1000  a 
 chinsoon 1.766827 2.060233 3.059109 2.379477 3.077080 67.16040  1000  a 
      TiC 1.986808 2.226933 3.472451 2.624236 3.397165 60.67802  1000   b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
dt[, val_lag := shift(val)[nafill(replace(seq.int(.N), rowid(rleid(val)) > 1L, NA_integer_), "locf")]]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e6
ng <- 1e5
dt = data.table(ID=sample(ng, nr, TRUE), val=as.character(sample(nr, nr, TRUE)))
setorder(dt, ID, val)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 3L,
    opt = dt[, val_lag := shift(val)[nafill(replace(seq.int(.N), rowid(rleid(val)) > 1L, NA_integer_), "locf")]],
    rle = dt[, val_lag := with(rle(val), rep(c(NA, head(values, -1)), lengths)), by = ID]
)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  opt  133.8857  159.8922  265.2029  185.8987  330.8614  475.8242     3
  rle 3097.6005 3123.5422 3193.2654 3149.4839 3241.0978 3332.7117     3
```

---

edit: added an example of what is happening:

```
index         |    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
value         |    a    a    a    b    b    c    c    c    d    d

shifted (s)   |   NA    a    a    a    b    b    c    c    c    d
rowid+rleid   |    1    2    3    1    2    1    2    3    1    2
replace       |    1   NA   NA    4   NA    6   NA   NA    9   NA <In ?nafill, Only double and integer data types are currently supported. Hence, nafill the indices before accessing>
nafill        |    1    1    1    4    4    6    6    6    9    9
using s above | s[1] s[1] s[1] s[4] s[4] s[6] s[6] s[6] s[9] s[9]
```

Comment: That's really brilliant solution! +1!

Comment: I just noticed that you didn't apply `by = ID`, which might affects both the desired output and the speed.

Comment: You are correct Thomas, if the solution does not use ```by = ID```, then ```val``` will look past the ```ID``` group, and values will spill from one group to another. Adding ```by=ID``` made this solution just a bit slower than ```rle``` solution.

Comment: I guess OP wants results with `by = ID`, otherwise a different output will be given

Comment: `shift` will lag the last value into the next group

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try the code like below

```
dt[,val_tag := c(NA,rle(val)$values)[cumsum(c(0,head(val,-1)!=tail(val,-1)))+1],ID]
```

and you will see

```
      ID val val_tag
   1:  A   a    <NA>
   2:  A   a    <NA>
   3:  A   a    <NA>
   4:  A   b       a
   5:  A   b       a
  ---
3996:  D   g       f
3997:  D   g       f
3998:  D   g       f
3999:  D   g       f
4000:  D   g       f
```

and

```
> tail(dt,30)
    ID val val_tag
 1:  D   d       c
 2:  D   e       d
 3:  D   e       d
 4:  D   f       e
 5:  D   f       e
 6:  D   g       f
 7:  D   g       f
 8:  D   g       f
 9:  D   g       f
10:  D   g       f
11:  D   a       g
12:  D   a       g
13:  D   a       g
14:  D   b       a
15:  D   b       a
16:  D   c       b
17:  D   c       b
18:  D   d       c
19:  D   d       c
20:  D   d       c
21:  D   d       c
22:  D   e       d
23:  D   e       d
24:  D   f       e
25:  D   f       e
26:  D   g       f
27:  D   g       f
28:  D   g       f
29:  D   g       f
30:  D   g       f
    ID val val_tag
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding ```grpid``` makes code much easier to understand.

Comment: @Saurabh You're welcome! If you care more about the speed, you can test both of them (I guess the first approach would be faster)

Comment: I have tried both solutions. The first approach gives the partially correct results. On running ```tail(dt, 30)``` there are several NA values, while the previous values exists. The second approach fills all values as NA.

Comment: @Saurabh See my update again, but I don't this my solution is fast

Comment: @Saurabh I don't think the answer by @chinsoon12 is the fastest since `by = ID` was not applied for `val_tag`. Your solution with `rle` in your post already is the fastest.

Comment: I have checked and you are correct. Out of available options, I already have the fastest solution with ```rle```.

Comment: @Saurabh I think it would be super nice if you can update your post with the benchmarking part such that other readers can easily get the point.

Comment: @TiC - I have added the benchmarking in the question. I think that removing functions ```head``` and ```tail``` in your solution will make it fast. Instead of ```tail```, ```.N``` can be used.

Comment: @Saurabh Good work! In `data.table`, perhaps you can try `first` and `last` to replace `head` and `tail`, respectively, maybe that would speed up. but I didn't test their performance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether grouping by `ID` is necessary in your example. You could basically look up a shifted named vector, which seems faster:

```r
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
ID = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 1000), rep("C", 1000), rep("D", 1000))
val = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c","d","d","d","d","e","e","f","f","g","g","g","g","g")
dt = data.table(ID, val)
lt <- setNames(c(NaN, seq_along(unique(val))), c(NA_character_, unique(val)))

microbenchmark(
    rle = dt[, val_lag := with(rle(val), rep(c(NA, head(values, -1)), lengths)), by = ID],
    TiC = dt[, val_lag := shift(unique(val))[as.integer(factor(paste(ID, val)))], ID], 
    me = dt[, val_lag := names(lt)[lt[val]]], 
    control = list(warmup=10)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#>   rle  614.544  653.2165  772.9975  775.7005  844.245 1391.390   100  b 
#>   TiC 1249.129 1286.2355 1578.1695 1412.4135 1553.035 6148.756   100   c
#>    me  330.570  346.1440  414.7982  386.9125  440.422  910.842   100 a

identical(dt[, val_lag:=names(lt)[lt[val]]],  
          dt[, val_lag := with(rle(val), rep(c(NA, head(values, -1)), lengths)), by = ID])
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: On running ```tail(dt,30)```, there are several NA values in ```TiC``` and ```me``` solutions; only ```rle``` produces the correct result.